How can i generate vcd file with recent version of Chisel?
I used to generate the vcd file through chiseltest like below.
import chisel3._
import chiseltest._
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec

class MyModuleSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with ChiselScalatestTester {
  behavior of "MyModule"
  it should "do something" in {
    test(new MyModule).withAnnotations(Seq(WriteVcdAnnotation)) { c =>
      c.io.in.poke(0.U)
      c.clock.step()
      c.io.out.expect(0.U)
      c.io.in.poke(42.U)
      c.clock.step()
      c.io.out.expect(42.U)
      println("Last output value : " + c.io.out.peek().litValue)
    }
  }
}

As far as i know keyword withAnnotations(Seq(WriteVcdAnnotation)) generates the vcd file
Modifying my code for newest version of Chisel, i edited my test code like below
import chisel3._
import chisel3.experimental.BundleLiterals._
import chisel3.simulator.EphemeralSimulator._
import org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.must.Matchers

class MyModuleSpec extends AnnFreeSpec with Matcher{

  " My module do something" in {
    simulate(new MyModule).withAnnotations(Seq(WriteVcdAnnotation)) { c =>
      c.io.in.poke(0.U)
      c.clock.step()
      c.io.out.expect(0.U)
      c.io.in.poke(42.U)
      c.clock.step()
      c.io.out.expect(42.U)
      println("Last output value : " + c.io.out.peek().litValue)
    }
  }
}

However, recent version of chisel which use svsim instead of chiseltest for test code cannot use this keyword withAnnotations(Seq(WriteVcdAnnotation)) with simulate function.
So, this code generates error.
I've been searching for the keywords that generate vcd in chisel test code.
Which keyword should i use for generating vcd file like older version of chisel in newest chisel?
Thank you.

I'm having the same issue, using the chisel-template project with chisel 6.2.0, have you found a solution?

As far as i know, there is no vcd generation in current version of chisel. However, i found the solution. See the details in this link https://github.com/rameloni/tywaves-chisel-demo. Thanks!

It turned out using chiseltest 6.0.0, vcd generation is also possible.
